# Gulp-twig console says "Error parsing twig template" despite rendered output being fine

Tags: gulp, twig

I have a page twig which consumes a component file which in turn consumes another file. I need to set all content for any of these files in the page file.

In my page twig file:

```
{% set content = {
  title: 'page title',
  accordion: {
    'text': 'TitleA'
  }
}
%}

{% include "component.twig" with content %}
```

In component.twig:

```
{% set settings = {
    'class': 'my-class',
    'style': 'primary'
  }|merge(accordion)
%}

{% include "button.twig" with settings %}
```

In button.twig:

```
<button class="{{ class }} button--{{ style }}" type="button">{{ text }}</button>
```

Im using gulp-twig. The above works however i get this error in my console.

https://github.com/zimmen/gulp-twig

```
Error parsing twig template /Users/me/myproject/src/components/component.twig:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_keys' of undefined
    at /Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:3579
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Twig.forEach (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:8:822)
    at Twig.filters.merge (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:3399)
    at Twig.filter (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:10126)
    at Twig.expression.definitions.parse (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:21538)
    at /Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:28849
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Twig.forEach (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:8:822)
    at Twig.expression.parse (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:28724)
Error parsing twig template /Users/me/myproject/src/components/component.twig:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_keys' of undefined
    at /Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:3579
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Twig.forEach (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:8:822)
    at Twig.filters.merge (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:3399)
    at Twig.filter (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:10:10126)
    at Twig.expression.definitions.parse (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:21538)
    at /Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:28849
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Twig.forEach (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:8:822)
    at Twig.expression.parse (/Users/me/myproject/node_modules/gulp-twig/node_modules/twig/twig.min.js:9:28724)
```

I can make the error going away by creating the following object. The weird thing however is that from looking at the page I can see TitleA is used not TitleB.

```
{% set accordion = {
  'text': 'TitleB'
}
%}
```

Ive tried different syntax eg:

```
{% include "button.twig" with accordion|merge({class: "my-class", style: "primary"}) %}
```

Comment: Are you sure _accordion_ is a available into component.twig? It seems to be undefined judging you stacktrace.

Comment: The values that I set in the mock object are rendered on the page so it must be available in some sense.

Comment: Twig unpacks the array you pass into the include into the context of component.twig, however, it appears that twig-gulp has an issue with that unpacking and is trying accordion from the current context before using the one passed in from the parent context. I don't use twig-gulp but am unable to reproduce your problem using php Twig, so it looks like it may be a bug in the way twig-gulp works.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution I discovered was to set an empty object as a default value before applying the merge filter e.g:

```
{% set foo = foo|default({})|merge(...) %}
```